# What does git fetch --prune origin do?

Tags: visual-studio, github, git

I have a local branch which needs to be removed. If I run git fetch --prune origin. It deleted 4 other branches. I would like to know what exactly git fetch --prune origin does?

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch --prune origin` will remove the branches which you have locally which are **stale**. Stale branches exist when the branch was deleted on the remote repository, but still exist on your local copy.